# 2 SSLs for single domain for quick server migration?

Tags: ssl

I have an SSL purchased from Godaddy assigned to a domain. I'm migrating hosting (not the domain) to a new server. After migration, we will begin testing the new server. Is it possible to set up a second SSL and link it to the same domain so that when we switch the new server live, there will be no downtime rekeying the SSL?

In other words, can I set 2 SSLs, each from two different providers, to work for a single domain?

Comment: Why? You can just use your existing SSL certificate.

Comment: The reason is because we would like both new and old servers to be able to run independently after the migration. We don't want to rekey the existing SSL. If there are any issues with the new server, we should be able to revert back to the old website with the prior SSL still in tact.

Comment: You still don't need a second SSL certificate. Unless you don't actually own your SSL certificate in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine. There's no limit on the number of SSL certificates you can have for a single domain. In fact, you can copy the existing cert over to the new server if you want.

Comment: Godaddy does not allow this. So we wanted to confirm if its something only Godaddy does, or if its global with all web host providers. Ultimately, we'd like 2 SSLs for the 1 domain so we can switch back to the old server in case something goes wrong with the new server.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Godaddy cannot keep you from copying the certificate to another server. As long as the domain is the same, the certificate will work on both servers.